# J2ME 2D - collisions detecting

Tags: java, java-me, lcdui

I am creating my own game for mobiles: 2D graphics, moving and shooting by soldier. And I got problem. I've two TiledLayer. First is ground, second contains walls, trees etc. How I can detect collisions with these objects placed on 2nd TiledLayer? I have tried so: if collision occured keep moving towards behind. It's wrong. I'm moving ahead and here's wall: press UP - ok, soldier goes DOWN. But when press LEFT soldier goes RIGHT in spite of it should go LEFT (I know that thus have written code).

However, how it'd be written?

```
 public void run() {
   while(true) {
    int keyState = getKeyStates();
       if ((keyState & LEFT_PRESSED) != 0) {
           soldier.setTransform(Sprite.TRANS_ROT270);
            if(!(soldier.collidesWith(traps, false))) {
             soldier.move(-10, 0);
           } else {
        if((keyState & LEFT_PRESSED) != 0) soldier.move(10, 0);
    }
  }  else if ((keyState & UP_PRESSED) != 0) {
      soldier.setTransform(Sprite.TRANS_NONE);
       if(!(soldier.collidesWith(traps, false))) {
        soldier.move(0, -10);
       } else {
        if((keyState & UP_PRESSED) != 0) soldier.move(0, 10);
    }
  }  else if ((keyState & DOWN_PRESSED) != 0) {
      soldier.setTransform(Sprite.TRANS_ROT180);
       if(!(soldier.collidesWith(traps, false))) {
        soldier.move(0, 10);
       } else {
        if((keyState & DOWN_PRESSED) != 0) soldier.move(0, -10);
    }
  }  else if ((keyState & RIGHT_PRESSED) != 0) {
      soldier.setTransform(Sprite.TRANS_ROT90);
       if(!(soldier.collidesWith(traps, false))) {
        soldier.move(10, 0);
       } else {
        if((keyState & RIGHT_PRESSED) != 0) soldier.move(-10, 0);
    }
  } else if((keyState & FIRE_PRESSED) != 0) {
    createBullet();
  }
```

Comment: please post code snippet you have problem with

Answer (score 1):

Consider [simplifying your code](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/extractMethod.html) and adding logging statements to make it easier to debug problems like you describe.

> ...how it'd be written?

Well below is about how I'd...

### [rewrite "it" before even attempting to drill...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refactoring)

...into what exactly went wrong in the particular corner of [the code snippet provided in question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code):

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        // extract method:
        handle(getKeyStates(), soldier.collidesWith(traps, false));
    }
}

private void log(String msg) { System.out.println(msg); } // simplify logging

private void moveSoldier(int dx, int dy) {
    // extract method to simplify logging
    System.out.println("move soldier, dx = [" + dx + "], dy = [" + dy + "]");
    soldier.move(dx, dy);
}

private void handle(int keyState, boolean soldierCollidesWithTraps) {
    // IMPL NOTE below code could (should) be refactored further
    if ((keyState & LEFT_PRESSED) != 0) {
        // IMPL NOTE consider extracting this block into dedicated method
        log("left pressed"); // log useful information
        soldier.setTransform(Sprite.TRANS_ROT270);
        if (!soldierCollidesWithTraps) {
            log("no collision");
            moveSoldier(-10, 0);
            return; // return as soon as we think we're done
        }
        // because of 'return' above, 'else' here is not needed anymore
        if ((keyState & LEFT_PRESSED) != 0) {
            log("left pressed - why re-check it here?");
            moveSoldier(10, 0);
            return;
        }
        log("no move"); // IMPL NOTE seems to be bug in your code logic above
        return;
    }
    if ((keyState & UP_PRESSED) != 0) {
        log("up pressed");
        soldier.setTransform(Sprite.TRANS_NONE);
        if (!soldierCollidesWithTraps) {
            log("no collision");
            moveSoldier(0, -10);
            return;
        }
        if ((keyState & UP_PRESSED) != 0) {
            log("up pressed - why re-check it here?");
            moveSoldier(0, 10);
            return;
        }
        log("no move"); // IMPL NOTE seems to be bug in your code logic above
        return;
    }
    if ((keyState & DOWN_PRESSED) != 0) {
        log("down pressed");
        soldier.setTransform(Sprite.TRANS_ROT180);
        if (!soldierCollidesWithTraps) {
            log("no collision");
            moveSoldier(0, 10);
            return;
        }
        if ((keyState & DOWN_PRESSED) != 0) {
            log("down pressed - why re-check it here?");
            moveSoldier(0, -10);
            return;
        }
        log("no move"); // IMPL NOTE seems to be bug in your code logic above
        return;
    }
    if ((keyState & RIGHT_PRESSED) != 0) {
        log("right pressed");
        soldier.setTransform(Sprite.TRANS_ROT90);
        if (!soldierCollidesWithTraps) {
            log("no collision");
            moveSoldier(10, 0);
            return;
        }
        if ((keyState & RIGHT_PRESSED) != 0) {
            log("right pressed - why re-check it here?");
            moveSoldier(-10, 0);
            return;
        }
        log("no move"); // IMPL NOTE seems to be bug in your code logic above
        return;
    }
    if ((keyState & FIRE_PRESSED) != 0) {
        log("fire pressed");
        createBullet();
        return;
    }
    log("no action");
}
```

Comment: @DamianCzapiewski _doesn't move_ interesting. I certainly missed the way you use side effects of multiple invocations of [getKeyStates()](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/game/GameCanvas.html#getKeyStates() "API documentation") (and likely of collidesWith(), too) but this would rather cause it move differently, not full stop. Do you trigger display refresh?