# Sprite Collision with Rectangle

Tags: java-me, sprite

I'm developing a game in j2me. I have a sprite and a rectangle moving around. how to check the collision between the sprite and rectangle.. ?

Answer (score 0):

LCDUI [`Sprite`](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/game/Sprite.html) class has the `collidesWith` methods. You should use one of them.
There is a good sample at this other answer: [J2ME 2D - collisions detecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742490/j2me-2d-collisions-detecting)